# Difference between Button with image, ImageButton, and clickable ImageView?

Tags: android, button, imagebutton

Is there any difference between `Button` with image, `ImageButton` and clickable `ImageView`?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

This probably only covers part of the differences, it would be helpful to actually look at the Android Source tree to see exactly what's going on.

ImageButtons has push states, where as a clickable image does not.
You also can't call setText for ImageButton, you can with a regular button.

They all derive from view, but looking at the following extends chain may help a little.

```
java.lang.Object
↳ android.view.View
   ↳ android.widget.ImageView
       ↳ android.widget.ImageButton
```

versus

```
java.lang.Object
↳ android.view.View
   ↳ android.widget.TextView
       ↳ android.widget.Button
```

Comment: Funny. Another example of problems caused by lack of (a sort of) multiple inheritance.

Comment: When to use one versus the other?

Comment: What exactly is a push state?

Comment: @ShikharMainalee the state of the button when it's being pressed/clicked. Also referred to as the compressed or down state.

Answer (score 19):

The differences can be subtle. The most direct way to understanding this is to start with looking at the docs. If you look at the [docs for Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) you can see that `Button` is derived from `TextView`. [`ImageButton`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) on the other hand is derived from `ImageView`. So fundamentally, a `Button` can have text and is clickable, whereas an `ImageButton` is a bit more flexible in how you set the image. It has methods from its `ImageView` base class like `setImageURI` which a `Button` does not. One of the differences between these two and just a plain `ImageView` is that you can have button states which is explained in both of the `Button` and `ImageButton` docs.

Answer (score 9):

```
ImageView = Display Images (android:src)
```

`ImageButton = Diaplay` Images as `imageView` and `get click` effect as button `(android:src)` and cannot set text to it.

```
Button = set text and (android:background)
```

Comment: Thank you this is syntax difference of setting. I needed to know actuall differences (when to use or the different look)

Answer (score 4):

One other aspect not mentioned in the previous answers is the usage within (for instance) a list item view. If you an embed a Button or ImageButton, the rest of the list item will not receive touch events. But if you use ImageView, it will.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? I just ran into this issue with `ImageButton`, but not with `Button` with image background

Comment: I'm afraid I no longer have access to the source in question. But it was pretty straight-forward - the button forms ate the touch event and the image view did not. I'm sure there are other ways to pass the event upstream, but this was a simple fix that required no refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

```
button instanceof ImageButton == false;
imageButton instanceof Button == false;
button instanceof TextView == true;
imageButton instanceof ImageView == true;
```