# What's the use of ImageButton

Tags: android, android-layout

When a background can be set on a Button then what is the use of an ImageButton?

Comment: but we cant set android:src in Button.

Comment: but even that serves the same purpose.

Comment: Take a look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420431/difference-between-button-with-image-imagebutton-and-clickable-imageview

Comment: "but even that serves the same purpose" -- no it does not. `ImageButton` allows you to specify separate images for the foreground and the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `ImageButton` (just like with `Image`) it is possible to control the way image defined by `android:src` is shown on the button: you can set [scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setScaleType%28android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType%29) - something you cannot do to the background.